# Some tags working, some doesn't in vim with ctags (Javascript code)

Tags: javascript, vim, ctags

I successfully generated `tags` file with `ctags -R`. I can go to function definitions with `CTRL-]` in `vim`, but not all of them are working (`E426: tag not found: someFunction`). I checked the content of `tags` file, and all the definitions are there.

What is the problem?

---

EDIT: The problem is that the semicolon (`;`) was missing in many places in the JavaScript-codebase. Browsers managed to interpret the code, but `ctags` generated `tags` file in a wrong way. I did a script that removed the unwanted prefixes from the identifiers and now it is working. But I also downloaded `jsl` and I'm removing (or adding) unwanted (or missing) semicolons. If this task will be finished, probably `ctags` will generate proper `tags` file.

Comment: Would it be possible that you are changing your working directory when jumping between buffers?

Comment: all JavaScript code is in the same directory

Comment: What about `:tselect someFunction`?

Comment: the same result when using `CTRL-]` or `:tag someFunction`

Comment: Would you mind sharing the tags file line that defines that function? Also share the contents of `@iskeyword`.

Comment: I figured out, that functions that are not working are starting with `function.someFunction` in the `tags` file, instead of `someFunction`... I removed the `function.` prefix, but still not working

Comment: you may not just remove function prefix, also sorted it when change the tag.

Comment: @SolaWing yes, but how to do that? `sort` itself is ignores some characters. How to sort the output which is also used by `ctags` ?

Comment: In Exuberant Ctags, if you use -V, you will see `system ("sort -u -o tags tags")`. so you also can use this sort cmd.

Comment: `echo -e ":zzzzz\nxxxxxx\n.aaaaa\n#fffff" | sort -u` is not working. It ignores the leading special characters

Comment: I have to use `LC_ALL=C sort`

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant parts of your code (point where you use `ctrl-]` and where `someFunction` is declared), as well as the relevant parts of the tags file. Also include all arguments used in the ctags call that generated the tags file.